# Create primary key on materialized view in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, view, materialized-views

How can I create a primary key on a materialized view in Postgres?

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW my_mat_view ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

returns error:

```
Error in query: ERROR: "my_mat_view" is not a table
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Materialized views cannot have primary keys. You can use a unique index instead.

```
create unique index on my_mat_view (id)
```